# How to loop over subarrays until the end of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy-slicing

Suppose that we have a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

What I'm looking for is a way to loop over subranges in the array starting from a position from the end. For example like this:

```
[4 5]
[6 7]
[8 9]
```

The following code does not work:

```
n = 6
m = 2
for i in range(0, n, m):
    print(a[-n+i:-n+i+m])
```

It prints:

```
[4 5]
[6 7]
[]
```

The problem is that in the last iteration the value to the right of : becomes 0. I can handle this with a condition like:

```
if -n+i+m == 0:
    print(a[-n+i:])
```

But I'm looking for a more elegant solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get slice starting from the needed position and [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
a[-n:].reshape(-1, m)
```

---

```
array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
```